# MySQL count 2 columns in a row and join with another query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, union

I have a table `visits` like this:

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| vis_id       | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| unit         | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| time_in      | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   |                |
| time_out     | timestamp   | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| in_username  | varchar(16) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| out_username | varchar(16) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

and a table `users` like this:

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| fname      | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| lname      | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| date_added | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   |                |
| username   | varchar(16) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| password   | varchar(40) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| auth_level | int(1)      | NO   |     | 1                   |                |
| last_login | timestamp   | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

I want to be able to count how many times each user is in `in_username` *AND* `out_username`... The query I was using before looks like this:

```
select count(*) as "count", u.fname as "fname" 
    from visits v
        inner join users as u on u.username = v.in_username
    group by u.username order by u.fname
```

But that only returns how many `in_username`'s there are... I'd like to have both in the same query if possible, so I could get results like this:

```
+----------+-----------+----------+
| count_in | count_out | fname    |
+----------+-----------+----------+
|      118 |       224 | Bo       |
|       27 |        64 | James    |
|      147 |       138 | Jeremy   |
|       23 |        37 | Jim      |
|      182 |       172 | Robert   |
|      120 |       158 | Tom      |
+----------+-----------+----------+
```

Where `count_in` is how many times their username appears in `visits.in_username`, and `count_out` is how many times their username appears in `visits.out_username`

Everything I've tried with `UNION` seems to add the counts together, or removes rows for some reason. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a subquery to get each total, combine them with `UNION`, and then merge them with `SUM()`.

```
SELECT SUM(count_in) count_in, SUM(count_out) count_out, fname
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) count_in, 0 count_out, in_username fname
      FROM visits v
      GROUP BY fname
      UNION
      SELECT 0 count_in, COUNT(*) count_out, out_username fname
      FROM visits v
      GROUP BY fname) combined
```

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly what I needed... I haven't seen `combined` before, is that a MySQL keyword?

Comment: Subqueries are required to have an alias, that's all that is.